# C# read and save propertys of printer devmode

Tags: c#, .net-core, printing

I have a simple application to copy the properties of the printer devmode and restore them after a manual change.

I read through topics the whole day and can't understand why my code isn't working. I compared the output of two different printer settings against each other and can confirm that they are different, so my guess is that something with restoring these settings isn't working.

I also tried [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488737/Storing-and-Recalling-Printer-Settings-in-Csharp-N) application but found some strange behavior. When I export the devmode data, change the properties manually and load the save again, the data only shows changed if I call the printer property dialog directly with the button in the application itself. If I go to windows settings and navigate to the printer properties myself, the data isn't changed.

Here is the code, got it from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452172/access-to-printer-settings-devmode-on-windows-7)

```
    public static class PrinterSettingsExtensions
{
    public static byte[] GetDevModeData(this PrinterSettings settings)
    {
        //Contract.Requires(settings != null);

        byte[] devModeData;
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try
        {
            // cer since hDevMode is not a SafeHandle
        }
        finally
        {
            var hDevMode = settings.GetHdevmode();
            try
            {
                IntPtr pDevMode = NativeMethods.GlobalLock(hDevMode);
                try
                {
                    var devMode = (NativeMethods.DEVMODE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                        pDevMode, typeof(NativeMethods.DEVMODE));

                    var devModeSize = devMode.dmSize + devMode.dmDriverExtra;
                    devModeData = new byte[devModeSize];
                    Marshal.Copy(pDevMode, devModeData, 0, devModeSize);
                }
                finally
                {
                    NativeMethods.GlobalUnlock(hDevMode);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hDevMode);
            }
        }
        return devModeData;
    }

    public static void SetDevModeData(this PrinterSettings settings, byte[] data)
    {
        //Contract.Requires(settings != null);
        //Contract.Requires(data != null);
        //Contract.Requires(data.Length >= Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.DEVMODE)));

        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try
        {
            // cer since AllocHGlobal does not return SafeHandle
        }
        finally
        {
            var pDevMode = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
            try
            {
                // we don't have to worry about GlobalLock since AllocHGlobal only uses LMEM_FIXED
                Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pDevMode, data.Length);
                var devMode = (NativeMethods.DEVMODE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                        pDevMode, typeof(NativeMethods.DEVMODE));

                // The printer name must match the original printer, otherwise an AV will be thrown
                settings.PrinterName = devMode.dmDeviceName;

                // SetHDevmode creates a copy of the devmode, so we don't have to keep ours around
                settings.SetHdevmode(pDevMode);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDevMode);
            }
        }
    }
}

static class NativeMethods
{
    private const string Kernel32 = "kernel32.dll";

    [DllImport(Kernel32, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport(Kernel32, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool GlobalUnlock(IntPtr handle);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct DEVMODE
    {
        private const int CCHDEVICENAME = 32;
        private const int CCHFORMNAME = 32;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME)]
        public string dmDeviceName;
        public short dmSpecVersion;
        public short dmDriverVersion;
        public short dmSize;
        public short dmDriverExtra;
        public int dmFields;

        public int dmPositionX;
        public int dmPositionY;
        public int dmDisplayOrientation;
        public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;

        public short dmColor;
        public short dmDuplex;
        public short dmYResolution;
        public short dmTTOption;
        public short dmCollate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHFORMNAME)]
        public string dmFormName;
        public short dmLogPixels;
        public int dmBitsPerPel;
        public int dmPelsWidth;
        public int dmPelsHeight;
        public int dmDisplayFlags;
        public int dmDisplayFrequency;
        public int dmICMMethod;
        public int dmICMIntent;
        public int dmMediaType;
        public int dmDitherType;
        public int dmReserved1;
        public int dmReserved2;
        public int dmPanningWidth;
        public int dmPanningHeight;
    }
}
```

I'm using .Net Core 6 and Windows 11 22000.795 if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

DevMode is what I am working on at the moment.  Using .net 4.8.1 unfortunately but I am using Heap functions and I am pulling the default settings using p/Invoke.
My goal is to modify settings and then stream the changed settings to another API.  So, I'll look into this and see what I can find.

Several steps could be giving you problems with settings.  Mostly around the printer/document/settings/defaults/drivers themselves.  Once you make your settings and pass need to make sure your end test is picking up the changes.  But, as you suggest, most likely an invalid format due to each driver being unique.

Any progress?

Comment: Additionally, look into DocumentProperties for updating.
Summary:
"Using a DEVMODE structure to modify printer settings is more difficult than just changing the fields of the structure. Specifically, a valid DEVMODE structure for a device contains private data that can only be modified by the DocumentProperties() function.

This article explains how to modify the contents of a DEVMODE structure with the DocumentProperties() function."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/modify-printer-settings-documentproperties

Comment: Steps 4 & 5 in above link are important.
#4: Modify the appropriate members of the returned DEVMODE structure and indicate which members were changed by setting the corresponding bits in the dmFields member of the DEVMODE. 

#5: Call DocumentProperties and pass the modified DEVMODE structure back as both the pDevModeInput and pDevModeOutput parameters and specify both the DM_IN_BUFFER and DM_OUT_BUFFER values (which are combined using the OR operator).The DEVMODE structure returned by the third call to DocumentProperties can be used as an argument in a call to the CreateDC function.

Answer (score 0):

Appears for the data to show it has been changed, you need to flag the fields that have been modified in public int dmFields;  (Says it is defined as a long).

dmFields

Specifies bit flags identifying which of the following DEVMODEW members are in use. For example, the DM_ORIENTATION flag is set when the dmOrientation member contains valid data. The DM_XXX flags are defined in wingdi.h.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).